# Extend/Omit interface in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

I have list of props under interface type. And want to extend interface type with modification as below,

1. Change of Prop types
2. addition of new fields

   ```
    interface Request {
      Id: NullProp<number>,
      Name: NullProp<string>,
      Code: NullProp<string>,
      Type: NullProp<string>,
      ValueType: NullProp<string>
    .....
    ...
    }
   ```

   /* trying to achieve like below */

   ```
        interface DataRequest extends Request {
          Id: number,
          Name: string,
          Code: string,
          Type: string,
          ValueType: string,
        .....
        ...,
          DataRequestId: number,
          DataRequestType: string
          DataValueType: NullProp<string>
        }
   ```

As found, we can do 'Omit' on derived interface but it will need long list of props as I have many interfaces like that and need to extend similar one.
Could you please advise if this should be separate new interface and duplicating props OR
any way to extend same interface ?

---

NullProp , type for Q | null | undefined

Comment: Is there anything special about `ValueType`, or should all the properties have the `NullProp<..>` wrapping removed?

Comment: All NullProps removed in extended and there will be some more added in derived types.

Comment: What is `NullProp`?

Comment: Its just type to allow NULL or undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can strip away the `NullProp`s into a separate type:

```js
type RemoveNullProp<T> = T extends NullProp<infer V> ? V : T;

type RequestWithoutNullProp = {
  [k in keyof Request]: RemoveNullProp<Request[k]>
}
```

and then extend that type with your extra properties:

```js
interface DataRequest extends RequestWithoutNullProp {
  DataRequestId: number;
  DataRequestType: string;
  DataValueType: NullProp<string>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response.  If some of props to skip from RequestWithoutNullProp ?  Is there way to skip 2 or 3 props from parent ?

Comment: You can omit multiple properties as required, e.g. `Omit<RequestWithoutNullProp, "DataSomeKey" | "DataOtherKey" | ...>`